# IONIC 2 - Return Dummy data from service

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-http

I am checking network availability on each http request with below code.

```
get(url) {
    this.createAuthorizationHeader();
    if (this.networkService.noConnection()) {
        this.networkService.showNetworkAlert();
        return Observable.of({ success: false });
    }
    else
        return this.http.get(HttpClient.ApiBaseUrl + url, { headers: this.headers });
}

post(url, data) {
    //return { "success": false };
    if (url !== 'Login')
        this.createAuthorizationHeader();
    if (this.networkService.noConnection()) {
        this.networkService.showNetworkAlert();
        return Observable.of({ success: false });//.delay(1000);
    }
    else
        return this.http.post(HttpClient.ApiBaseUrl + url, data, { headers: this.headers });
}
```

In my service file i am handling response & error.

```
public extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();       
    return body || {};
}

public extractError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure

    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}


getClientServiceById(serviceId: any) {
    if (!serviceId)
        serviceId = this.emptyGuid;

    return this.httpClient.post('Service/Detail', { serviceId: serviceId })
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.extractError);
}
```

When network is available everything is working fine. Bun net is disconnected i am getting error in **map** . error is **res.json is not a function**.

Can anyone tell me how pass json object in map??

Comment: You are returning a plain object and not a Response object which would have .json() function.. Why not just throw an error ? Observable.throw and handle it in your catch?

Comment: I had shown error messages  in some api. so it will display message twice. can you tell me how return custom Response object?